# How can I extract the date and other values from a the string in PHP

Tags: php

How I Separate the date and pax name and Room Type

---

```
[Description] => Hotel reservation in PHUKET, THAILAND for Patong Beach from 08/01/2016 to 15/01/2016
Room Type: Double (Superior) Breakfast
Pax name: Mr tareq boqrais
Reservation ref: ETS378620-3000100
```

---

I need like the output

```
CIDate: 08/01/2016
Codate: 15/01/2016
Room Type: Double
Pax name: Mr tareq boqrais
Reservation ref: ETS378620-3000100
```

Comment: Try to start from explode function .. ist explode with : than it will be easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$exp = explode(" ", $des);

foreach($exp as $k => $val)
{
  if($val == 'from')
      $cid = $exp[$k+1];
  if($val == 'to')
      $cod = $exp[$k+1];
}
echo "<pre>";
//var_dump($exp);
echo (substr($cid, 0,10));
echo (substr($cod, 0, 10));
echo trim(GetBetween("Room Type:","Pax",$des));
echo "</pre>";

function GetBetween($var1="",$var2="",$pool)
{
$temp1 = strpos($pool,$var1)+strlen($var1);
$result = substr($pool,$temp1,strlen($pool));
$dd=strpos($result,$var2);
if($dd == 0){
$dd = strlen($result);
}
return substr($result,0,$dd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other content is fixed? If it is, you can use RegExp to find them out. The RegExp is useful, I think you should master it. So, I suggest you study it.